# Can we use sqoop to export data from Hadoop (Hive) to Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, etl, sqoop

I have a local Hadoop cluster and want to load data into Amazon Redshift. Informatica/Talend is not an option considering the costs so can we leverage Sqoop to export the tables from Hive into Redshift directly? Does Sqoop connect to Redshift?

Answer (score 5):

The **most efficient way** to load data into Amazon Redshift is by placing data into Amazon S3 and then issuing the `COPY` command in Redshift. This performs a **parallel data** load across all Redshift nodes.

While Sqoop might be able to insert data into Redshift by using traditional `INSERT` SQL commands, it is not a good way to insert data into Redshift.

The preferred method would be:

- Export the data into **Amazon S3** as CSV format (preferably in .gz or .bzip format)
- Trigger a `COPY` command in Redshift

You should be able to export data to S3 by copying data to a Hive **External Table** in CSV format.

Alternatively, Redshift can load data from **HDFS**. It needs some additional setup to grant Redshift acces to the EMR cluster. See Redshift documentation: [Loading Data from Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-from-emr.html)

Answer (score 0):

copy command not supporting upsert it just simply load as many times as you mention and end up with duplicate data, so better way is use glue job and modify it for update else insert or use lambda to upsert into redshift